# VBA function doesn't compile

Tags: excel, vba

I have got a very simple function in VBA in which I work on a Range with multiple columns and rows. First I wanted to sort that Range over first column (filled with dates):

```
Public Function getCOF(data_zawarcia_tf As Date, waluta_tf As String, czas_trwania_tf As Double, _
                        table_to_search As Range, output As Range) As Double
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    table_to_search = table_to_search.Sort(Key1:=Range("A1"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending)
    MsgBox "h"
    MsgBox table_to_search(1, 1)
    czas_trwania_tf = -Int(-czas_trwania_tf / 12) * 12
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If table_to_search(i, 1) < data_zawarcia_tf And table_to_search(i, 2) = "S" And _
            waluta_tf = table_to_search(i, 3) And czas_trwania_tf = table_to_search(i, 4) Then
            getCOF = output(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    

End Function
```

but when I do this this way, the function doesn't even call MsgBox (can you tell me why I don't even get an error?). The function doesn't compile and i get `#ARG!` in my cell.
I also tried to do:

```
Public Function getCOF(data_zawarcia_tf As Date, waluta_tf As String, czas_trwania_tf As Double, _
                        table_to_search As Range, output As Range) As Double
    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    table_to_search.Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), _
                     Order1:=xlAscending
    MsgBox "h"
    MsgBox table_to_search(1, 1)
    czas_trwania_tf = -Int(-czas_trwania_tf / 12) * 12
    For i = lastRow To 1 Step -1
        If table_to_search(i, 1) < data_zawarcia_tf And table_to_search(i, 2) = "S" And _
            waluta_tf = table_to_search(i, 3) And czas_trwania_tf = table_to_search(i, 4) Then
            getCOF = output(i)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
    

End Function
```

and this time the function do call MsgBox, but `MsgBox table_to_search(1, 1)` with ascending sort is same as with descending.

How can I sort my Range object?

Also is there a way to work on Range as on python's/R's dataframe? That is something like

`get_value = my_range(my_range(all_rows, 1) = "12.02.2005", my_range(all_rows, 2) = "Los Angeles")(3)`
that means `get_value` would be value from 3rd column where 1st and 2nd columns are "12.02.2005" and "Los Angeles"

Answer (score 2):

User Defined Functions (UDF) – functions that can be called from cells like the built in Excel formulas – are not allowed to change other Excel cells. So you cannot `Sort` in them nor can you change the value of other cells. The only thing a UDF can do, is return a value to the cell where it is used as formula.

The issue is: You are not allowed to use `Sort` in this function. Therefore the code throws an exception at this line and errors.

Comment: And how can I sort a range to work on within the function? I mean I load the values as a "table" (dataframe) `table_to_search` and I want to sort it within the function, do stuff, extract one value that my function will return?

In python i would write: `def func(table): table = table.sorted() return table[1]` or smth like that so the function would get table, sort it only in it, but do not change the data, and return 2nd value of already solved table

Comment: @Saguro the only thing you can do is to read all the values into a multidimensional array and then write a procedure to sort that array (do some research there are tutorials on how to sort an array). Then use that array to find your desired data. • The issue is `Sort` on a sheet will change the cells in the sheet and that is not allowed to be done by UDFs

Comment: and for real there is no implemented function to sort an array within a function?

Comment: There is no VBA built-in sort function.  There are a number of VBA sorting functions you can find with an internet search.  Or, for a 1D array, you could use the `ArrayList` object (part of  `System.Collections`).

Comment: @Saguro there is for real no implemented function. But have a look here on Stack Overflow there is a lot of solutions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vba+sort+array